# conda pyinstaller builded exe not working in window server 2016, kernalbase.dll exception module not found from mkl_intel_threding.dll

Tags: pyinstaller

conda pyinstaller builded exe in window server 2016 and not working another pc with window server 2016 (without conda). in in-time debugger showing

The thread 0x43c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF88C8C4C48 (KernelBase.dll) in main.exe: 0xC06D007E: Module not found (parameters: 0x0000006A94AF6F90).

Already copied all mkl_*.dll and new version of mkl dll too.

callstack

```
mkl_intel_thread.dll!00007ff859ea32e0() Unknown
mkl_intel_thread.dll!00007ff859ea8235() Unknown
mkl_intel_thread.dll!00007ff85834d9c1() Unknown
mkl_intel_thread.dll!00007ff8583cbc3c() Unknown
mkl_rt.dll!00007ff85d54c698()   Unknown
mkl_rt.dll!00007ff85d5dd01f()   Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy call mkl_intel_thread.dll and getting some issue from kernalbase.dll
may numpy core creating issue.
So, I just force updated numpy. (remove conda numpy and add pip numpy)

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```